# Hibernate - Restrictions (Calendar, HOUR)

Tags: hibernate, hql, restriction, restrictions

Can I get items created at **specified hour** (e.g. **9am**) from the table using by hibernate restrictions (i mean ids 130, 146, 147, 148)?

[image]

Can you tell me how (`createDate` is in `Calendar` format in Java)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be done using Restrictions? Can't you use something else? If yes then you should be able to do it with something like this:

```
Restrictions.sqlRestriction("DATEPART(hour,createDate) = 09")
```

Not sure about the 0 in 09 and didn't test it myself but don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Right, it's SQL so = :) No problem.